# I got execute bad access here but how come?

Tags: objective-c, exception

```
+(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSMutableDictionary *managedObjectContexts =BGMDCRManagedObjectContextThreadHandler.singleton.managedObjectContexts;

    if (managedObjectContexts[[self threadKey]] == nil ) {
        @synchronized(self)
        {
            NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType ct=nil;
            if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                ct = NSMainQueueConcurrencyType;
            }
            else
            {
                ct = NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType;
            }

            NSManagedObjectContext *threadContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:ct];
            threadContext.parentContext = [self managedObjectContextMainContext];//This is always the same moc
            threadContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
            managedObjectContexts[[self threadKey]] = threadContext;
        }
    }
    NSManagedObjectContext * moc= managedObjectContexts[[self threadKey]]; //Execute bad access here
    return moc;
}
```

I still use old style managedObjectContexts management where each thread has it's own managed object context.

Anyway, if (managedObjectContexts[[self threadKey]] == nil )  is doing just fine.

Also I did some po and got:

```
(lldb) po [self threadKey]
0xcd7b9a0
(lldb) po managedObjectContexts
{
    0xcd7b9a0 = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1552d050>";
    0xd81fe20 = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0xcb6f230>";
    0xd8dd9d0 = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x17406cc0>";
}
(lldb) po managedObjectContexts[[self threadKey]]
<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1552d050>
```

Clearly everything is fine. So what EXC_BAD_ACCESS could mean?

[image]